# optionsText is not applying in my knockout select object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout-mvc

I'm working with in my first knockout experience and have been learning quite a bit.  What I'm attempting to do is populate a new object and push it into the viewModel for display.

The select box ( drop down box) is populating but when I click on add, the object name is blank.  Then it occurred to me, I have two fields I need to collect from to assemble the object so I'm not sure I'm going about this the right way....

My data model:

```
    function Colors(data) {
    this.ID = ko.observable(data.ID);
    this.ColorName = ko.observable(data.ColorName);
    this.Duration = ko.observable(data.Duration);
}
```

View:

```
<table id="NewColor">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="SelectColor" data-bind="options: AllColors, optionsText: 'ColorName', value: AllColorss.ID, optionsCaption: 'Select Color...'"></select>
            <input id="Duration" data-bind="value: Duration" />
            <button data-bind='click: addColor'>Add Color</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The input ID="duration" isn't working / populating right but I'm working on getting the model data to update....  (This is a side issue I'll look at later so of there's syntax issues there, that's why)

The script to add from the button click:

```
        self.addColor = function() { self.AddColors.push(new Color(NewColor )) };
```

When that runs, the ColorName is blank in the following table but a blank entry is added.

Display / update table:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th padding: 10px; >Color</th>
        <th padding: 10px; >Duration</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: AddColors">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: ColorName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Duration"></td>
        <td>
            <a href='#' data-bind='click: $parent.removeLine'>Remove</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Is what I'm doing the way to add an object into the array for the newly created object?  I don't see a SelectedColor.SelectedText or anything similar.  How do I access the text property of the select drop down list?

Comment: I should also mentioned I tried populating the list manually using {ColorName:SelectColor...} but I couldn't find a text value to set, just the .value which is the ID num.

Comment: I'm not really clear as to what problems you are having. First you mention the `select`, then that the 'duration' `input` isn't working and finally that an entry is added when you click the button but the `ColorName` is blank (what about the Duration?). I'm not really sure I understand your actual problem, so please edit your question and clarify. My guess is that you have two problems, you're not binding the `NewColor` bindings to the `NewColor` object (but this is just a guess) and you don't use the `options` bindingHandler correctly (the `value` bindingHandler looks odd).

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify what the actual issue is. If you could also make a jsfiddle ([jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)), jsbin ([jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com)) or plunker (http://plnkr.co/) which shows your viewmodel and bindings and shows your issue, this would help a great deal in assisting you. Regarding the `options` binding on the `select` element, I suggest you go through [the `Working with Lists and Collections` tutorial at learn.knockoutjs.com](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections).

Comment: I was just notifying readers that there is an issue there but I haven't looked at the duration problem.  The issue I'm working with is the select box and getting the text / currently selected item from the box.  It looks like I may have been trying to do this wrong; it appears I may have to create a variable and assign it to the value= in the select.  I only had an hour or so last night when I found that article and haven't had much luck with that yet.  I do plan on looking at it further shortly here.

Comment: Have you gone through the tutorial mentioned above? Have you been able to solve your problem or are you still having issues?

Comment: Sorry; was a crazy day yesterday and no coding.  I don't have it solved yet, but it looks like that tutorial is going to work great.  I didn't realize those tutorials existed; I'm going to spend some time in them. Thanks Robert!  I'll update when resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if what I was doing before would work but I backed off what I had and added in the select box after the line was added which was the same thing the tutorial was doing.  That worked.  I can't thank you enough, Robert.